# How to order a character vector in ascend form in R

Tags: r

Hi everybody I am trying to  solve a problem in R. I want to read a lot of files allocated in multiples sub folders in a main folder. Then I used `list.files()` to get sub folders but when I use the function it makes mistakes due to `b` vector is in different order. Vector `b` is the next:

```
b=list.files()
b
 [1] "A1"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "A13" "A14" "A15" "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7" 
[14] "A8"  "A9"
```

And its structure is the next:

```
chr [1:5] "A1" "A2" "A3" "A4" "A5"
```

I would like to have my `b` vector in this form:

```
b
 [1] "A1" "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7" "A8"  "A9" "A10" "A11" "A12" "A13"
[14] "A14" "A15"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It doesn't work give me the same result and I need to order b! @Fernando

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this. Here's another one:

```
b <- c("A1","A10","A11","A12","A13","A14","A15","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7")
b[order(nchar(b), b)]
# [1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "A13" "A14" "A15"
```

Answer (score 2):

`gtools::mixedsort` is designed for this...

```
gtools::mixedsort( c("A1","A10","A11","A12","A13","A14","A15","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7") )
[1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "A13" "A14" "A15"
```

Thanks to @Matthew for the data

Comment: Hah. While I was messing around trying to build an example that demonstrated the full power of mixedsort, you scooped me.

Comment: @DWin I *think* it was you who put me on to `mixedsort`. I *love* this function, I use it all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than focussing on a particular example I suggest using an existing tool, `mixedsort` in the gtools package that handles irregular widths of both the alpha and numeric characters.

```
require(gtools)
vec <- paste0( replicate(40, {
            paste( sample(LETTERS, 3, repl=TRUE),collapse="")}),  
                sample(1:400, 40, repl=TRUE) ) 
mixedsort(vec)
 [1] "ABP256" "ATV361" "ATZ12"  "BKL273" "BOY273" "BQJ242" "CQL129"
 [8] "CXH313" "CXQ249" "DFU116" "FGI305" "HJK249" "ICN4"   "IML75" 
[15] "JDJ309" "JEB93"  "JHF276" "JIY265" "JXK287" "KCQ282" "MAR161"
[22] "MGV185" "MHH72"  "NDJ84"  "NGZ84"  "OIV207" "ORK31"  "PSJ95" 
[29] "QOC178" "QXL344" "QYK285" "RFO98"  "ROC135" "TUL40"  "UBT134"
[36] "UKP14"  "VQL372" "YLG393" "ZLD394" "ZSG180"
```

If `mixedsort` didn't exist man would need to invent it. This is not exactly going to produce the same results but it might light a path forward:

```
vec[ order( gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", vec), gsub("[[:alpha:]]", "", vec) )]
 [1] "ABP256" "ATV361" "ATZ12"  "BKL273" "BOY273" "BQJ242" "CQL129"
 [8] "CXH313" "CXQ249" "DFU116" "FGI305" "HJK249" "ICN4"   "IML75" 
[15] "JDJ309" "JEB93"  "JHF276" "JIY265" "JXK287" "KCQ282" "MAR161"
[22] "MGV185" "MHH72"  "NDJ84"  "NGZ84"  "OIV207" "ORK31"  "PSJ95" 
[29] "QOC178" "QXL344" "QYK285" "RFO98"  "ROC135" "TUL40"  "UBT134"
[36] "UKP14"  "VQL372" "YLG393" "ZLD394" "ZSG180"
```

It collapse all the alpha characters together before the numerics and would `order` "a12b" before "a99z".

Comment: +1 a rather more comprehensive demonstration of the power of `mixedsort`

Answer (score 1):

If this is the exact data that you have, you can sort it the way you want like this:

```
> b[order(as.integer(substr(b,2,3)))]
 [1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12"
[13] "A13" "A14" "A15"
```

If the actual data is more complicated, you might have to do a little more string manipulation, but this is the general idea.

Comment: You can also replace `substr(b,2,3)` by `sub("[A-Z]", "", b)`.

Comment: Thanks but a little question your solution would work with a string that has a structure from A1 to A70, all elements are disorded! @mrip

Comment: A1 to A70 would work.  If it gets to 100 you need to do `substr(b,2,4)`, or you can use @Jilber's solution which will work for more general cases (i.e. if the first letter is something other than A, etc).